# Iptables rules sometimes are reset automatically

Tags: iptables

Can't figure out why iptables rules are dropped.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 89.111.3.48 -j DROP
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Think you might need to expand.  Do you mean you have a set of iptables rules and they sometimes *all* vanish, or only some of them vanish? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: Entirely vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 89.111.3.48 -j DROP

If you just run the above command, it just loads that rule into the kernel, not really changing the iptables file. This would be lost on a reboot or a restart of iptables.

`service iptables save`

would save the rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables and the change would survive a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-A` is adding the rule to the **end** of the INPUT rules. iptables works on first match wins. My guess is that some earlier rule is allowing the connections from the listed IP address and so your rule is never seeing them.

Solution: use `-I`

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s 89.111.3.48 -j DROP
```

This will insert your rule at the beginning of the INPUT table. For further information have a look at the [**iptables**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) man pages.