# How to load a list of addresses into iptables, dynamically?

Tags: iptables

Now, I want to dynamic loading a ip list file for iptables .the ip list file is the accept host , default drop . 
example,

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -s 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

I mean to open a port for some one  , but the ip list is dynamic,Whether I can do like below ,

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -s ip-list-file -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT

ip-list-file:
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Have any idea ? Thank you .

=========================================

I look at [Iptables rules sometimes are reset automatically](https://serverfault.com/questions/283323/iptables-rules-sometimes-are-reset-automatically/283327#283327) , I can use -I ,insert the rule to head of the chain . 
How to realize the dynamic loading the ip list file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't simply provide a filename to the `-s` parameter. If you only have a few addresses (in the order of 10s), you can use a script to add multiple rules:

```
while read IP; do
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -s $IP -j ACCEPT
done < ip-list-file
```

If you have lots of addresses you should rather use the [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) mechanism:

```
ipset create list0 iphash
while read IP; do
    ipset add list0 $IP
done < ip-list-file
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1111 -m set --match-set list0 src
```

Comment: Thanks, I am writing a web service to operate the iptables.I will use iptables -I and -D .Any good suggestions?

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -s ip1,ip2,ip3 -j ACCEPT`